# Get correct positions in the array to insert in database correctly

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i want to save the values in one array where have the following positions:

```
array[1] -> id_resp
array[2] -> corp_resp
array[3] -> date  
array[4] -> menuId
array[5] -> id
array[6] -> id_resp
array[7] -> corp_resp
array[8] -> date  
array[9] -> menuId
array[10] -> id
      .
      .
```

There you can see the var_dump is given in that page and the table where need to get the values.

[image]

There is what is in database and what we need to have correctely in database:

```
    id_resp     corp_resp        date         MenuId    id

    654           0.3          2016-11-25        6      28    <- inserted in database wrong.



 Correct need to be that to be the output in the database:

        654           0.3          2016-11-25        4      28 
        655           0.3          2016-11-25        5      28  
        656           0.35         2016-11-25        6      28
```

That is the code after the option value submitted. There is given the wrong output like you can see in the top.

```
 $id_resp = (isset($_POST['id_resp']) ? $_POST['id_resp'] : '');
 $corp_resp = (isset($_POST['corp_resp']) ? $_POST['corp_resp'] : '');
 $id = $_SESSION['UtilizadorID'];
 $data = (isset($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : '');
 $menuId = $_SESSION['menuID'];

 var_dump ($menuId);

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO respostas 
                    (id_resp, corp_resp,id,data,menuId) 
             VALUES ('','" . $corp_resp . "','" . $id . "', NOW( ) , '$menuId')")  
    or die("Alguma coisa correu mal durante o registo. MySQL erro: ".mysql_error());
```

Comment: You say you want 3 rows created but you only attempt to create one row ????

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: @RiggsFolly, yes and is wrongly that is inserted in the database. Is posible to define one array in that way?